# Prepared Statement not working while Statement is working with Java and Oracle

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to run a simple query to fetch data using Java 1.6 and Oracle 9i.
Even though I am getting the result with a statement but while using `preaparedstatement` result set returned with empty rows. Have any body faced the same issue?

My JDBC driver version is 10.1.0.5.0
and DB is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production

Following is the program.

```
String query = "SELECT count(SEVERITY) as CNT FROM TICKET_TABLE where upper(customerid)=?" ;
PreparedStatement pst =null;
ResultSet lResultSet = null;
pst = con.prepareStatement(query);      
pst.setString(1, "CUST_A");
lResultSet = pst.executeQuery();                
while(lResultSet.next()) {                      
  i = lResultSet.getInt("CNT");
}
lResultSet.close();
pst.close();
con.close();
```

Comment: If you expecting only one row, should replace `while` with `if`...

Comment: Wrong - while is fine. Doesn't explain why there are no results from PreparedStatement.

Comment: Was not an answer, just a comment...

Comment: BTW what do you mean by "empty rows"?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you used 'Statement' and it worked?

Comment: Define 'returned with empty rows'.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto If you're only expecting one row it doesn't make the slightest difference whether you use `while` or `if`. Comment notwithstanding.

Comment: empty means its execution went inside the while loop but retuned zero count  but when i ran this directly in sqldeveloper its returned actual count.

Comment: One other consideration: doesn't adding upper() to the WHERE clause force you to scan the entire table?  That query will be inefficient.  If you have an index on customerid, and you should, the call to upper() will make it useless.

Comment: If you expect a single row, but get multiple rows, the single result (EG `i`) would be the last row's result and that might be empty...

Comment: Was the "empty" row `NULL` or zero?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Now it is your turn to define 'empty row'.

Comment: "0" is the return.

Comment: `getInt()` would return `0` even if the column is `NULL`, as `int` cannot hold `NULL` value. One can test the returned value for `NULL` by calling `ResultSet.wasNull()` method afterwards.

Comment: APP-1 [Not Working]
Java 1.5 ,JDBC driver version is 9.2.0.1.0
DB is Oracle
DB Ver is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production
 Oracle installed on Solaris 5.10

APP-2 [Worked]
========
Java 1.5 ,JDBC driver version is 9.2.0.1.0 ,
DB is Oracle
DB Ver is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production
Oracle installed on Solaris 5.10

App3 [Worked]
====
Java 1.5 ,JDBC driver version is 9.2.0.1.0
DB is Oracle
DB Ver is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
Oracle installed on Windows Enterprise 2003

Answer (score 0):

You can check the compatibility of the oracle driver you are using with the java version and database version.

Secondly, confirm that the query criteria suppose to return records by running it first through any Oracle client tool.

Comment: Same query returned data with sqldeveloper 4.2

Comment: Confirm the compatibility of the jdbc driver you are using with the db version , java version and the OS. Oracle drivers can be funny at times.

Comment: APP-1 [Not Working] 
Java 1.5 ,JDBC driver version is 9.2.0.1.0
DB is Oracle
DB Ver is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production
 Oracle installed on Solaris 5.10

APP-2 [Worked]
========
Java 1.5 ,JDBC driver version is 9.2.0.1.0 ,
DB is Oracle
DB Ver is Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production
Oracle installed on Solaris 5.10

App3 [Worked]
====
Java 1.5 ,JDBC driver version is 9.2.0.1.0
DB is Oracle
DB Ver is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
Oracle installed on Windows Enterprise 2003